# Conversion of a recursive function

Tags: c++

The following program is a recursive function that computes a value from two positive integers.

```
int riddle (int i, int j)
{
   if (j==0) return i;

   return riddle(j, i%j);
}
```

I was wondering how one while-loop can convert this program into a non-recursive function without any if -statement?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: put the conditional in the while statement

Comment: let him do the homework on his own

Comment: it will always returns ith value what you are supplying?

Comment: Note that this only works because this is a tail-recursive function. If it wasn't, you'd need to use a local stack to maintain history state.

Comment: Hint: `return riddle(j, i%j);` can be turned into `int old_i = i; i = j; j = old_i % j; goto the_beginning_of_the_function;`.  You're technically done at that point, but your teacher will probably deduct points for hideosity.  :)

Comment: BTW, this is very close, if not identical, to the function to find the GCD of two numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Your comment does provide more idea for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming i>j, your prog to find HCF of two no.s using recursion can be done using while. try this :

```
int i=val1,j=val2;
            while (j != 0)
            {
                int t;
                t = j;
                j = i % j;
                i = t;
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.The program functions well. Since I am not good at C++, I was wondering if you could explain why it works?

Comment: Does it mean that t act as a local stack to maintain history state?

Comment: sorry 4 the delayed response, wasn't looking at the terminal for a while. The recursive program simply kept on assigning your 'i' val of 'j' and 'j' val of '(prev i)%j' with each recursion until the value of 'j' that is 'i%j' passed from prev func call became 0. so the main condition was to keep on doing the above task until constantly changing value of 'i%j' became 0. 't' is not a local stack, it's just a temporary variable you use to store value of j before assigning it a new value of 'i%j'. I can not use i=j directly as in next step j=i%j will give wrong result. relate it to swapping logic

Comment: I don't know if u really understood my clumsy explanation (I am not very good at explaining things in "writing"), but if it helped you, then I am happy. Pleasure was mine :P

Comment: your explanation is good in which it inspires my idea in doing this program. Thanks for your help again.

Answer (score 0):

First, you identify the condition for ending the recursion, and that will be the condition to end your `while` loop.

Next, you identify the statements to be executed during recursion, and those will form the body of your `while` loop.

Lastly, you identify the statements to be executed upon the end of the recursion, and those will be performed right after the `while` loop.

Pseudocode:

```cpp
while condition to perform recursion is true
{
  perform statements to be executed during recursion
}
perform statements to be executed upon exiting recursion
```